# Android sound file editing app with unlimited waveform editing zoom

Tags: android, audio-editing

As a Android user, I want an app that allows me to:

1. Open a sound file in whatever sound format.
2. View the sound file in a waveform editor.
3. Select a section of sound file.
4. Zoom in *as deeply as possible, without any limits on depth of the zoom*.
5. Cut that section of waveform out, deleting all other parts.
6. Save the sound file to either that same file (overwriting), or Save As to a different sound file in the same folder.

Typical files are very small: On the order of 10 seconds or less, e.g., ringtone or notification files. See the sample audio file at https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_itt7D1N0AiczZjMkp2cG9mMFZ1dUFocVdyN05QZ0ZNZm1Z for a sound file of a finger snap near the end. I want to clip out all of the sound *other* than the finger snap (see several screenshots of waveform editors in various apps below).

No matter what app I have tried in the sections below, all of them limit the zoom depth in some manner.

Is there an app somewhere on the Play Store that provides unlimited waveform editing zoom, or am I out of luck and have to use desktop apps for this?

---

### RingMaker Pro

Play Store link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.herman.ringtone.paid

[image]

Also seems to limit the size of the sound file, which is bad for very small sound clips.

---

### MP3 Cutter

Play Store link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mp3.cutter.ringtone.maker.trimmer

[image]

---

### PocketBand - Social DAW

Play Store link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.uloops.android

Very complicated. Could not even find out how to open up a simple file in the waveform editor. Could not figure out how to stop the tutorial. Probably a very good app if I wanted to spend a whole day viewing online tutorials and messing around. So that's a no go.

Found this via https://techviral.net/best-audio-editing-apps-for-android/

---

### Audio MP3 Cutter Mix Converter and Ringtone Maker

Play Store link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appzcloud.audioeditor

[image]

This app had the most intuitive interface of the others I had tried. Too bad it also suffers from the limit on zoom depth.

---

### Audio Clipper

Play Store link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bakerst.audioclipper

[image]

Another case where zoom is limited.  Hmmm, starting to see a trend here in that perhaps all of these apps are using the common library and maybe the common library itself is to blame for these limits, and not the apps themselves?

Answer (score 1):

Doninn http://www.doninn.com/products/mobile-apps/doninn-audio-editor

or

VoicePRO http://www.voicepro.it

Not sure about zoom, however.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Those do look promising and professional. All of the apps I have mentioned in the original post are free.  Both of those apps you mentioned are >= 10 USD. And no, I didn't constrain the question to be "free apps".  However, I'm not going to spend money on a hunch that they handle deep zooming.